# jQuery Cookie plugin to save select value?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a series of two chained selects using ajax that work great.  I need to be able to store/save the first select in a cookie for future visits but can't quite figure out how/what to do within the existing code?

```
$(function(){

    var questions = $('#questions');

    function refreshSelects(){
        var selects = questions.find('select');

        //  Lets not do chosen on the first select
        selects.not(":first").chosen({ disable_search_threshold: true });

        // Listen for changes
        selects.unbind('change').bind('change',function(){

            // The selected option
            var selected = $(this).find('option').eq(this.selectedIndex);
            // Look up the data-connection attribute
            var connection = selected.data('connection');


            // Removing the li containers that follow (if any)
            selected.closest('#questions li').nextAll().remove();

            if(connection){
                fetchSelect(connection);
            }

        });
    }

    var working = false;

    function fetchSelect(val){

        if(working){
            return false;
        }
        working = true;

        $.getJSON('citibank.php',{key:val},function(r){

            var connection, options = '';

            switch (r.type) {
                case 'select':
                    $.each(r.items,function(k,v){
                        connection = '';
                        if(v){
                            connection = 'data-connection="'+v+'"';
                        }

                        options+= '<option value="'+k+'" '+connection+'>'+k+'</option>';
                    });

                    if(r.defaultText){

                        // The chose plugin requires that we add an empty option
                        // element if we want to display a "Please choose" text

                        options = '<option></option>'+options;
                    }

                    // Building the markup for the select section

                    $('<li>\
                        <p>'+r.title+'</p>\
                        <select data-placeholder="'+r.defaultText+'">\
                            '+ options +'\
                        </select>\
                        <span class="divider"></span>\
                    </li>').appendTo(questions);

                    refreshSelects();
                    break;
                case 'html':
                    $(r.html).appendTo(questions);
                    break;
            }

            working = false;
        });

    }

    $('#preloader').ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).show();
    }).ajaxStop(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

    // Initially load the product select
    fetchSelect('callTypeSelect');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need that value on the server? If you don't I recomment the [jStorage plugin](http://www.jstorage.info/). It uses local storage and userData to save information. This has the benefits that the [values are not sent to your server on every request](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/request#ServeFromCookielessDomain), like cookies do.
The usage is very simple:

```
$.jStorage.set("something", {data: [1,2,3], other: "a string"});
```

and

```
$.jStorage.get("something"); // returns {data: [1,2,3], other: "a string"}
```

In your code it would be something like:

```
$(function() {
  var questions = $('#questions');
  var lastSelection = $.jStorage.get("lastSelection");
  if(lastSelection) {
     questions.find("select:first").val(lastSelection);
  }

  // more code....

  selects.unbind('change').bind('change',function(){
    var selected = $(this).find('option').eq(this.selectedIndex);
    if(questions.find("select:first")[0] === this) { // Only save if it's the first combo (you could change this to a better way to identify the first select)
      $.jStorage.set("lastSelection", selected);
    }

    // more code....
});
```

Comment: ...not necessary to store on the server.  How would I fit your answer into the existing code exactly?  I am very new to this and was hoping to learn by watching.

Comment: I don't know what value you are trying to save... is it the "selected" variable of the change event?

Comment: Yes, I want to save the selected value from the first select box change event.  thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is great article on using `jCookies`.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/04/j-is-for-jcookies-http-cookie-handling-for-jquery/

The code for setting it goes like this:

```
$.jCookies({
    name : 'Person',
    value : { first: 'John', last: 'Smith', Age: 25 }
});
```

Getting the cookie goes like this

```
var person = $.jCookies({ get : 'Person' });
```

Comment: can you give me a more specific example based on the snippet i supplied?

Comment: You're going to be more specific with your code a bit more if you want a specific example. I understand the general idea, but you didn't really explain it out. Also, in theory I would check for a cookie off the bat, if it doesn't exist then go on like it's a new selection. When the user makes a selection then create a cookie that stores the information you need. The tutorial I provided has plenty of information for you.